# Rewriting a method to be unit-testable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, unit-testing, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I find that I often like to write methods that just query database and return the results. This is really helpful with complex filters or query 'chaining'. For example, here is a model `Clazz` that represents an academic class of students. `Clazz` has many `Enrollment`s. So I wrote this method to keep my code DRY, since I used this criteria a lot.

```
class Clazz
    def cash_enrollments
        enrollments.where(payment_type: 'cash')
    end
end
```

As I get more into unit testing, I noticed that this pattern is problematic because it is too tightly coupled with the database. The problem is exacerbated when testing large datasets as the database transactions run.

Is there a "unit test friendly" way to rewrite this code? Is there another common pattern that would be better?

Comment: You could stub it out: `clazz.should_receive(:cash_enrollments).and_return([this_prebuilt_array])`

Comment: not completely sure but do check out repository pattern

Answer (score 0):

You could probably try this http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/ Extract Query Objects or Service Objects